# Is there a way to dynamically generate sessionid for a request in api.ai

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

i have a nodejs rest api that hits api.ai wit a query. I want to generate a unique session ID for each user who accesses the app.

If I use the same session ID for all the requests I am afraid that the data(entities) of one request will be used for another request as the session ID is same.

So is there any way by which i can obtain an access troken from an agent in api.ai

Comment: what exactly is your setup? if you are using the botframework, you can use its conversationId as your api.ai session id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just generate unique ids, there is some packages in npm implementing that in various ways, like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

But for everything related to the separation of session data, I suggest that you dig into the details of the web server, they usually provide a way to separately handle request and sessions.

**EDIT**: For example, if your using express server, a session id is present in every request at `req.sessionID`

Comment: thanks.. i used express-session to generate session id and req.sessionID worked